# Alternative to additemtodock from Henri Shustak

Tags: macos, command-line, dock

I am using a commandline script to add items to the dock via scripts

http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/23653/add-item-to-dock

But it seems to have a lot of bugs and maybe even "kills" my Dock config file. Are there any good alternatives out there to add *.app properly to the dock ?

Comment: Do you have the latest version? Latest version : http://www.lucid.technology/tools/additemtodock

Answer (score 3):

Open **Applications / Utilities / AppleScript Editor** and paste this:

```
my add_item_to_dock(choose file of type {"APPL"} with prompt "Choose an application to add to the Dock:")
on add_item_to_dock(item_path)
try
        get item_path as alias -- you need a POSIX path so this coerces the path in case it's an HFS path, alias, file ref, etc.
        set item_path to POSIX path of item_path
    end try
    try
        tell application "Dock" to quit
    end try
    do shell script "defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '<dict><key>tile-data</key><dict><key>file-data</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</key><string>" & item_path & "</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>0</integer></dict></dict></dict>'"
    try
        tell application "Dock" to activate
    end try
end add_item_to_dock
```

Save it as *Script* or *Application*.

Comment: Can i directly use it in my "normal" shell script as function ? Or won't it work because its apple script

Comment: To Run and AppleScript from shell you'll need to use the `osascript` command. You can either call the AppleScript directly (`osascript -e 'applescript command'`) or run the script (`osascript script.scpt`). If you are parsing the AppleScript directly, you'll need to *rephrase* it so it can be run in one line.

Comment: You can also include newlines in the argument after `-e`, get the script from stdin, or use a HEREDOC.